# Understanding integrals with spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, 3d, spherical-coordinates

[image: An image of the 3d figure obtained above the cone z=sqrt(x^2 + y^2) and below the sphere x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1]

Hi! I am studying for an exam and working on understanding spherical coordinate integrals. For the integral below there is a cone and a sphere. I saw a solution to this problem which involved translating to spherical coordinates to get a triple integral. The integral solved was(p^2)*sin(phi). How does one go about obtaining this? I understand how to calculate the bounds. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$\rho^2\sin\phi$ is the "fudge factor" in spherical coordinates; i.e., $dV = \rho^2\sin\phi\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

the Jacobian.

$dx \ dy \ dz = \left|\det\begin{bmatrix} \frac {\partial x}{\partial \rho} &\frac {\partial x}{\partial \theta}&\frac {\partial x}{\partial \phi}\\
\frac {\partial y}{\partial \rho} &\frac {\partial y}{\partial \theta}&\frac {\partial y}{\partial \phi}\\
\frac {\partial z}{\partial \rho} &\frac {\partial z}{\partial \theta}&\frac {\partial z}{\partial \phi}\end{bmatrix}\right| \ d\rho\ d\phi \ d\theta = \rho^2\sin\phi \ d\rho\ d\phi \ d\theta$

What does it mean?  Starting at some $(\rho, \phi, \theta)$, nudge each of the variables.  $(\rho + d\rho,\phi, \theta), (\rho,\phi+d\phi, \theta)$, etc.  Nudging each of these, creates a "box" of some volume.  What is the volume?